# devise pegar usuário logado

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Pessoal eu tenho uma aplicação simples usando o ruby on rails a gem rails admin e devise para autenticar

eu tenho um model chamado tarefa onde toda tarefa pertence a um usuário , so que eu gostaria de pegar o usuário que esta logado no momento e atribuir automaticamente na hora de criar uma nova tarefa , pois no momento estou tendo que selecionar na hora de criar a tarefa algum dos id dos usuários que existe cadastrado no devise

como sou iniciante tentei ler a documentação tanto do rails admin como o do devise e nao conseguir achar nada muito claro que possa me ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você não postou o seu codigo vou lhe mostrar um exemplo.

Na view você vai remover o select que te pede para selecionar as IDs dos usuarios. Você só vai associar o USUARIO a TAREFA no Create de seu controler.

No exemplo abaixo eu estou associando a uma tarefa o usuario logado. A logica é essa, seu codigo ficara diferente por causa das validações, redirecionamentos etc...

```
def create
   #crio o objeto com os parametros que a view me enviou.
   @task = Task.new(params_task)

   #No objeto task criado estou associando o usuario logado
   @task.user = current_user
   if @task.save
       #se tudo deu certo voce redireciona
       redirect_to root_path
   else
       render :new
   end
end
```